# Android Keystore decrypting encrypted data gives incorrect result

Tags: android, encryption, kotlin, android-keystore

I'm trying to encrypt a arbitrary String using a KeyPair generated by an instance of `java.security.KeyPairGenerator`. Unfortunately after encrypting and decrypting the String with the generated KeyPair the result is incorrect.

here is how I go about doing this:

```
val ks: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore").apply {
    load(null)
}

fun encryptUsingKey(publicKey: PublicKey, bytes: ByteArray): ByteArray {
    val inCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/NoPadding")
    inCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey)
    return inCipher.doFinal(bytes)
}

fun decryptUsingKey(privateKey: PrivateKey, bytes: ByteArray): ByteArray {
    val inCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/NoPadding")
    inCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey)
    return inCipher.doFinal(bytes)
}

fun getKey(): KeyStore.Entry {
    val containsAlias = ks.containsAlias(alias)
    if (!containsAlias) {
        val kpg: KeyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
            KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA,
            "AndroidKeyStore"
        )
        val parameterSpec: KeyGenParameterSpec =
            KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                alias,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT
            )
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false)
                .build()

        kpg.initialize(parameterSpec)

        val kp = kpg.generateKeyPair()
    }
    return ks.getEntry(alias, null)
}
```

My encryption/decryption test looks like this:

```
fun testEncryptionDecryption() {
    val entry = getKey()

    if (entry is KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) {
        val privateKey = entry.privateKey
        val certificate = entry.certificate
        val publicKey = certificate.publicKey

        val testKey = "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF"

        val encrypted = service.encryptUsingKey(publicKey, Base64.decodeFromString(testKey))
        val decrypted = service.decryptUsingKey(privateKey, encrypted)

        assertEquals(testKey, Base64.encodeToString(decrypted))

    }
}
```

Unfortunately the result looks like this:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF]> but was:<[AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANNdt-Oeu_PQAQgxBdNdt-Oeu_PQAQgxBdNdt-Oeu_PQAQgxBdNdt-Oeu_PQAQgxBQ]>
```

Can someone enlighten me to what's going on here? Where do all these A's come from? Am I using the keys incorrectly?

Comment: Use RSA with `NoPadding` is both insecure and incorrect. RSA decryption needs to know the length of plaintext. RSA randomized padding takes care of that as well as the security needs. OAEP padding is the currently the best for RSA so use that,

Comment: @JamesKPolk I tried to incorporate your suggestions but now I get an `java.security.InvalidKeyException: Keystore operation failed` exception...

Comment: Did you change `setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)` to reflect the paddings you used?

Comment: yes I set it to `KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP` and get the cipher with `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/OAEPPadding")`

Comment: @AKroell why are you using RSA?  AES will be much faster (less power consumed) and it doesn't look like you actually need the asymmetric properties of RSA here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suspected it was incorrect configuration. The following works:

`val inCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding")`

```
val kpg: KeyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
            KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA,
            "AndroidKeyStore"
        )
        val parameterSpec: KeyGenParameterSpec =
            KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                alias,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT
            )
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_ECB)
                .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA1)
                .build()

        kpg.initialize(parameterSpec)
```